# Scope Inheritance $broadcast in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events, datetimepicker, angular-ui

I'm trying to set scope broadcasting in Angular. Datetimepicker should be defined in parent grid, children should inherit it. I tried this way:

```
      $scope.dtBODStopValue = new Date()
      $scope.dtBODStartValue = new Date(new Date(new Date().getTime() - 7 * MS_PER_DAY));
```

Changing Date/Time and broadcast to other grids

```
        $scope.dateTimePickerBODStart = {
        change: function () {
                $scope.$broadcast(dtBODStartValue,dtBODStopValue);
          $scope.OnGridRefresh();
        }
      };

$scope.dateTimePickerBODStop = {
        change: function () {
                $scope.$broadcast(dtBODStartValue,dtBODStopValue);
          $scope.OnGridRefresh();
        }
      };
```

HTML:

```
    <input kendo-date-time-picker="dateTimePickerBODStart" k-ng-model="dtBODStartValue" k-options="dateTimePickerBODStart"/>
    <input kendo-date-time-picker="dateTimePickerBODStop" k-ng-model="dtBODStopValue" k-options="dateTimePickerBODStop"/>
```

Comment: `$scope.$broadcast` for broadcasting to childs and `$scope.$emit` for broadcasting to parent

Comment: should it be like my edited correction? unfortunately it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per documentation $broadcast is method of scope

```
$scope.$broadcast(name, args);
```

so in your case it should be

```
$scope.$broadcast('datepickerUpdate', dtBODStartValue, dtBODStopValue);
```

and then for listeners in `child` scopes

```
$scope.$on('datapickerUpdate', function (event, dtBODStartValue, dtBODStopValue) {
  //do stuff on change
})
```

Comment: hello, can you please tell me how should I put my "stuff on change" if I want only to select a date? Probably is very easy but I cannot solve it in the moment, thank You